# Matching a parameter

Tags: ruby, regex, match

Can the following method in Ruby help to scan an input string prepending with hash?

```
def foo(bar)
  (bar.scan(/^#/).empty?) ? "##{bar}" : bar
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--what do you want returned, under what circumstances? Won't this just make sure there's a `#` at the beginning?

Comment: So this method will return bar guaranteeing a leading hash, are you looking for more information than that?

Comment: Why dont you just put this in irb and test it out?

Comment: @DaveNewton, Yes it makes sure that there's a # in the beginning of the string.

Comment: @shahkhan What's the question then?

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to make it bit more easy and understanding by simplifying the code. I mean i want to try an alternate for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same with:

```
if bar.start_with?('#')
  bar
else
  "##{bar}"
end
```

Or using a ternary:

```
bar.start_with? '#' ? bar : "##{bar}"
```

Comment: @Dave Newton, Thanks to you also.